# How do I close the channel correctly?

Tags: go, concurrency, goroutine

As far as I understand the deadlock appears because the channel is not closed. How do I close the channel to get rid of the deadlock?

I use this library to limit the number of goroutines: https://github.com/zenthangplus/goccm

Code:

```
func main() {
   c := goccm.New(5)
   chanStr := make(chan string)
   lines := []string{"aaaaaa", "fffff", "ddddd", "eeeee"}

   for _, value := range lines {
      value := value
      c.Wait()
      go func() {
         chanStr <- value
         c.Done()
      }()
   }

   for value := range chanStr {
      fmt.Println(value)
   }
   c.WaitAllDone()

}
```

Before that I did with the channel done to realize that all goroutines are complete and close the channel, but before that I did not limit the number of goroutines.

Comment: I'd recommend using [errgroup](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/sync/errgroup) instead of goccm, as it is part of the standard library and most likely fulfills all the needs you have.

Comment: @M.Becerra, Thank you) I'll have to look into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read from the channel in another goroutine:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/zenthangplus/goccm"
)

func main() {
    c := goccm.New(2)
    chanStr := make(chan string)
    lines := []string{"aaaaaa", "fffff", "ddddd", "eeeee"}

    go func() {
        for value := range chanStr {
            fmt.Println(value)
        }
    }()

    for _, value := range lines {
        value := value
        c.Wait()
        go func() {
            chanStr <- value
            c.Done()
        }()
    }

    c.WaitAllDone()
    close(chanStr)
}
```

Comment: That almost solved my problem. If I change the number of goroutines to 1 or 2 or 3 (c := goccm.New(2)), the deadlock appears again. Is it a problem with the library I'm using or is it a general problem?

Comment: That's because when there are not enough slots, `c.Wait` in the `for` loop is blocked. I have updated the demo to address this issue. The solution is to create the goroutine that reads from the channel first; so that it will read from the channel and free up slots.

Comment: Everything is fine thank you)